# Error while executing migration - Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, magento2.2.0, magento1.9.2.3, data-migration

Migrating (trying to) but there is an error with I don't know what to do.

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]

There are no commands defined in the "migrate" namespace.

Any ideas?

Comment: HI did you got any answer?

Comment: Yes actually I managed to migrate some data but in the meantime because We decided not to move to Magento 2 yet everything is gone. Will do it again soon then probably will post a step by step guide how to.

Comment: @JenithSamuel you installed the Data Migration Tool by uploading files to app/code ?

Answer (score 2):

This error goes away when the data **migration tool is installed using composer**.

I debugged bit deeper into this error and found that the module's code of adding its shell commands are not working correctly. I didn't spend time to correct it instead installed the data migration tool using composer and it worked!

And, just in case, if you get **Wrong Credential message** when installing the tool using composer, you need to **type the private key in the password field**. The normal pasting password function(on right click) didn't seem to work here. This made me choose to install the tool manually, LOL.

Comment: Great thanks for this information, will check it asap as I must rebuild Magento 2 site.